# Onclick fullscreen and play video

Tags: video, fullscreen

I have a .mov video which I need to play in fullscreen after click on a button or element.

The fullscreen thing is working, the only thing I need now is to play when it's fullscreen. So I need 2 events to be triggered when clicking the button or element. 1 is to go fullscreen and 2 is to play.

I have this code to go fullscreen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goFullscreen(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

```
<body>

    <video class="video_player" id="player" width="100%" height="100%" poster="images/placeholder.png">
    <source src="video/video.mov"/>
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag.  Use a better browser!
    </video>
    <button class="toggle-btn" id="togglePlay" onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false">
        View Fullscreen!
    </button>

</body>
```

So on the click it will go fullscreen (all fullscreen without the scrollbars and toolbars) but now I need it to play also when it's fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video id="videoplay" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"> 
    <source src=small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
    <source src=small.3gp type=video/3gp>
    <source src=small.webm type=video/webm> 
    <source src=small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
</video>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVideo = document.getElementById('videoplay');
myVideo.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (myVideo.paused) {
      if (myVideo.requestFullscreen) {
        myVideo.requestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (myVideo.msRequestFullscreen) {
        myVideo.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
      else if (myVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        myVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }
      else if (myVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        myVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }
      myVideo.play();
    }
    else {
      myVideo.pause();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We appreciate your effort in writting this answer but sadly it is not a good answer. Please take a moment to read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) :)